# Two OneToOneFields for the same table are not allowed in Django models

Tags: django, database, django-models

so I am trying to store the user's location coordinates in another table by linking it to the original using a OneToOneField.

```
class Coordinates(models.Model):
    lat = models.FloatField()
    lng = models.FloatField()


class Trip (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) #Drivers Profile
    departure = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    departureCoord = models.OneToOneField(Coordinates, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    arrival = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    arrivalCoord = models.OneToOneField(Coordinates, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date = models.DateField(validators=[inthe_future])
    time = models.TimeField(default=datetime.now().time())
    vacant_seats = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    vehicle_used = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    price_per_person = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, default='UPCOMING', max_length=10)

    def __str__ (self):
        return f"{self.user.first_name} - ({self.departure} => {self.arrival})"
```

I have used an OneToOneField for both `arrivalCoord` and `departureCoord` since each row on the `Coordinates` table is going to uniquely link the departure and arrival of every Trip.

So by still having a one-to-one relationship, is it possible for me to get the same thing done as when I try to run `makemigrations` I'm thrown with this error.

```
←[31;1mapp.Trip.departureCoord: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'app.Trip.departureCoord' clashes with reverse accessor for 'app.Trip.arrivalCoord'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app.Trip.departureCoord' or 'app.Trip.arrivalCoord'.←[0m
←[31;1mapp.Trip.departureCoord: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'app.Trip.departureCoord' clashes with reverse query name for 'app.Trip.arrivalCoord'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'app.Trip.departureCoord' or 'app.Trip.arrivalCoord'.←[0m
```

I think there is a better way to improve the design of the database, are you'll aware of anything?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is my latest migration file...

```
# Generated by Django 3.2.3 on 2021-06-18 04:22

import datetime
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app', '0020_alter_trip_time'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Coordinates',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('lat', models.FloatField()),
                ('lng', models.FloatField()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='trip',
            name='time',
            field=models.TimeField(default=datetime.time(9, 52, 22, 413173)),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='trip',
            name='arrivalCoord',
            field=models.OneToOneField(default=0.0, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, related_name='arrivalCoord', to='app.coordinates'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='trip',
            name='departureCoord',
            field=models.OneToOneField(default=0.0, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, related_name='departureCoord', to='app.coordinates'),
        ),
    ]
```

I have created the `Coordinates` table and the OneToOneField for the first time.

Comment: Are you using [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#geodjango-database-api)? If you were you could use [PointField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#pointfield) instead of your separate `Coordinates` model

Comment: Well even in that case I can just use FloatField in my code, but I feel using GeoDjango might complicate my code a bit more and I have no clue on how to use GeoDjango. Like is there anything else that comes could be useful? @IainShelvington

Comment: If you want to continue using FloatFields: to continue using your models as they are add `related_name='departures'` to `departureCoord` and similar to `arrivalCoord` OR remove the `Coordinates` model completely and the fields in two so there is no relation

Comment: Well i tried the 1st method using the `related_name` method but, when running `python manage.py migrate`, I was thrown with this error. `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__app_trip.arrivalCoord_id`

Comment: Have you changed the `arrivalCoord` field from a `ForeignKey` to a `OneToOneField`?

Comment: No, I haven't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a unique `related_name` to each `OneToOneField` so that unique reverse relationships can be added to the `Coordinates` model

```
class Trip (models.Model):
    ...
    departureCoord = models.OneToOneField(Coordinates, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='departure')
    arrivalCoord = models.OneToOneField(Coordinates, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='arrival')
    ...
```

Comment: Heyyy real sorry, i got an error could u check it out pls

Comment: @Najaaz Are you adding these fields to an existing model or changing them after they were previously defined? If so, can you add the migration file to the question and explain exactly what the change was?

Comment: I have added mylatest migration file to the question.

Comment: @Najaaz a `OneToOneField` must be unique, you can't provide a default when the migration asks you. You need to delete that migration and then allow null values in those fields `null=True, blank=True` before creating another migration. After you have set all the new fields to have a value you can then add the constraints back